# What metals can be melted inertly in alumina crucible?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, metal, metallurgy

Specifically, a crucible made from 90+% Aluminum Oxide.  What metals can be melted in it without any weird reaction taking place?

Comment: Could you elaborate as to what you think would be a "weird reaction"?

Answer (score 1):

I would suppose that the manufacturer would provide details as to what the melting point of the crucible is....and it probably isn't a good idea to find for yourself. Anyhow for sure you can melt gallium.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallium

But it probably cannot melt tungsten.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten

Comment: I meant common engineering metals, like metals bicycles or cars would be made out of... :D